# Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

Tags: jwt, .net-6.0, bearer-token, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Although my jwt token is validated for all the params but i am getting this error when i called a [Authorize] method from controller. I can find the solution. please help me to debug that.I have checked my token from jwt.io. the token payload is absolutely okay. Still I am getting the error. please help me to solve the issue. Thanks a lot.

Following is the `Program.cs`

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
    using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using TestAzureToken;
    
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // Retrieve AzureAd settings from appsettings.json
    var azureAdSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");
    // Configure TokenValidationParameters
    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        RequireSignedTokens = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = azureAdSettings["Issuer"],
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = azureAdSettings["ClientId"],
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
    
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            options.SaveToken = true;
        });
    
    builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("allowAny", o => o.AllowAnyOrigin()));
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.MapControllers();
    
    app.Run();
```

and my `appsetting.json` is given below -

```
{
  

    "AzureAd": {
        "Instance": "https://devlinqxfracpro.b2clogin.com/",
        "Domain": "devlinqxfracpro.onmicrosoft.com",
        "TenantId": "66d0dc3b-jhgbj-86c93172e100",
        "ClientId": "6380bbd7-bhjghg-b3e2-15371c1c8503",
        "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
        "ClientSecret": "",
        "ClientCertificates": [],
        "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_signupsignin1",
        "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_fracpro-signup",
        "SignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signupsignin1",
        "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_fracpro-password-reset",
        "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_fracpro-pe",
        "Issuer": "https://abvcfg/v2.0/"
      },
      "AzureAdB2C": {
        "Instance": "https://devlinqxfracpro.b2clogin.com/tfp/",
        "ClientId": "6380bbd7-be16-48cd-b3e2-15371c1c8503",
        "Domain": "devlinqxfracpro.onmicrosoft.com",
        "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_fracpro-signup"
      },
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning"
        }
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "MicrosoftGraph": {
        "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
        "Scopes": "user.read"
      },
      "DownstreamApi": {
        "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
        "Scopes": "user.read"
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'd immediately delete and rotate that secret if I was you...